# could not find or read file in karate feature file

Tags: maven, api, karate

when I am trying to read the `json` or js file I am getting the error

---

> could not find or read file

```js
function() {
    
      return { 
          Authorization: "Bearer 32635fe69a7033023f82aa9d8c5bc8dd",
          "X-Account" : "7ad93b7d-714a-4f70-82ef-92de407f0245"
   
  }
}
```

```
a.json
   {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer 32635fe69a7033023f82aa9d8c5bc8dd",
    "X-Account" : "7ad93b7d-714a-4f70-82ef-92de407f0245"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really cannot make out from whatever information you have provided. It is most certainly some simple mistake you are making and no one else has reported anything similar.

I suggest you create a fresh project using the maven archetype: https://github.com/intuit/karate#quickstart

Then use that pom.xml and project skeleton as a base and get things to work.

EDIT: I also think the problem may be that `X-Account` needs to be within quotes like this: `"X-Account"` - note that `-` is an invalid character for JSON keys (as it will be treated like a minus sign).

Comment: i created project with the maven when i use mvn test command to test feature file  then i am getting this error but when i moved the project to another location it is working fine

Comment: @nitihngupta ok please accept the answer then, thanks.